# Loop through checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, loops, checkbox, foreach

Lets say I have a table containing a list of car dealers.

I also do have a list that contains wich manufactor the car's related to.

- Example: `assigned_id`, `assigned_carid`, `assigned_cardealer`.
- Example 2 (list of dealers): `dealer_id`, `dealer_name`

I need to have all the dealers printed as a checkbox, and the selectboxes must be checked if the car is related to a dealer.

How to do that in PHP/MySql? Foreach?

Comment: Post an example of your approach with code and we'll help you.  SO is not about providing base level code.  This sounds like a school assignment to me...

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the arrays from your database and echo each fetched array. If you echoing the data, echo also a html checkbox after it.

Comment: But, i need to check also if the checkbox is checkeded or?